# selecting specific node with xpath in powershell

Tags: xml, powershell

I am trying to select a specific node in an xml file for the purposes of comparing it to the same node in another file.

I can navigate through the file using the generic nodes, but I can't figure out how to get an exact Xpath.

Here's the XML:

```xml
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <!-- Domain wide values -->
  <PropertyGroup>
    <LoggingLevel>0</LoggingLevel>
    <LongTimeouts>0</LongTimeouts>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <!--AB-->
    <Token Include="{AB_ANALYTICSSERVER}">
      <Value>Test</Value>
    </Token>
    <Token Include="{AB_CERTFINDVALUE}">
      <Value>$(CertName)</Value>
    </Token>
    <Token Include="{AB_SERVICECERTFINDVALUE}">
      <Value>$(CertName)</Value>
    </Token>
    <Token Include="{AB_CONSUMERSGROUP}">
      <Value>DLG-AB-users</Value>
    </Token>
    <!--AB End-->
    <!--Database-->
    <Token Include="{Database_Domain}">
      <Value>$(Domain)</Value>
    </Token>
    <Token Include="{Audit_Domain}">
      <Value>$(Domain)</Value>
    </Token>
    <!--Database End-->
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

But I am clearly missing something in my xpath based queries:

e.g. 
`$xmlNew.SelectNodes("/node()[1]/node()[3]/node()[2]").outerxml`

Returns:

`<Token Include="{AB_ANALYTICSSERVER}" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003"><Value>Test</Value></Token>`

But neither of these return anything:

`$xmlNew.SelectNodes("/Project/ItemGroup/Token").outerxml`

`$xmlnew.selectnodes('//token[contains(@Include,"{AB_ANALYTICSSERVER}")]').OuterXml`

Similarly this works:

`$xmlNew.SelectNodes("/node()[1]/node()[2]/node()[2]").outerxml`

but this doesn't:

`$xmlnew.selectnodes('/Project/PropertyGroup/LongTimeouts').outerxml` doesnt.

What obvious thing am i missing? :/

Thanks

Comment: The default namespace set on the `Project` element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your XPath isn't valid because of the namespace.

You can abuse PowerShell's power however and simply access `Token` as if it was an object structure.

```
$xmlNew.Project.ItemGroup.Token.outerxml
```

You can also use `Select-Xml` cmdlet and specify the namespace explicitly with your XPath as it is shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19309613/446515).

```
$ns = @{dns = 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003'}
Select-Xml -Xml $xmlNew -XPath '//dns:Token' -Namespace $ns
```

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but i tried to literally follow the example in your link, but couldn't get it to work: 
$ns =@{dns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003"}
$tokens = Select-Xml -Xml $xmlnew -XPath '//dns:token' -Namespace $ns
$tokens | Foreach {$_.Node.Name}

Comment: @MalcolmLock Probably a case-sensitivity issue in your XPath, I added a working example in my answer.

Comment: If you tried my code in the last 5 minute, there was an error in it. My bad.

Comment: Thanks! I'm still having trouble getting selectnodes and selectsinglenode to work with the NS, but i think this gets me what i need.