# PowerShell, how to select an xml node

Tags: xml, powershell, selectsinglenode

I cannot select the `FirstLogonCommands` node. Why does `$firstLogonCommands` always come back as `null` and how can the `FirstLogonCommands` section be properly selected?

```
# Load the XML content
$xml = @"
<unattend xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:unattend" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State">
  <settings pass="offlineServicing">
  </settings>
  <settings pass="windowsPE">
    <component name="Microsoft-Windows-International-Core-WinPE" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS">
      <SetupUILanguage>
        <UILanguage>en-US</UILanguage>
      </SetupUILanguage>
      <InputLocale>0809:00000809</InputLocale>
      <SystemLocale>en-GB</SystemLocale>
      <UILanguage>en-US</UILanguage>
      <UserLocale>en-GB</UserLocale>
    </component>
  </settings>
  <settings pass="oobeSystem">
    <component name="Microsoft-Windows-International-Core" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS">
      <InputLocale>0809:00000809</InputLocale>
    </component>
    <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Setup" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS">
      <FirstLogonCommands>
        <!-- Content here -->
      </FirstLogonCommands>
    </component>
  </settings>
</unattend>
"@

# Create an XML document object
$xmlDocument = New-Object System.Xml.XmlDocument
$xmlDocument.LoadXml($xml)

# Select the FirstLogonCommands node
$firstLogonCommands = $xmlDocument.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode('//settings[@pass="oobeSystem"]/component[@name="Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Setup"]/FirstLogonCommands')

# Check if the FirstLogonCommands node exists
if ($firstLogonCommands -eq $null) {
    Write-Output "FirstLogonCommands section not found under 'Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Setup' component in the 'oobeSystem' settings pass."
} else {
    Write-Output "FirstLogonCommands section found:"
    Write-Output $firstLogonCommands.InnerXml
}
```

Comment: The xml has a namespace. This question is a duplicate of [How do I access an element with xpath with a namespace in powershell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19309001/how-do-i-access-an-element-with-xpath-with-a-namespace-in-powershell)

Comment: I tried to use the code you referenced, and I'm still left with completely null output. What you provided is probably obvious to those with better knowledge of xml,, but it is not an answer in itself. `$ns = @{dns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:unattend"}; $items = Select-Xml -Xml $xml -XPath '//dns:item' -Namespace $ns`. Could you give me a few extra pointers please? I've provided a complete xml layoutt in my question, but still I have `null` output, so I don't see how the other question answers this (maybe it does, but I don't see how to implement it here).

Comment: I've also tried in this way `$items = Select-Xml -Xml $xml -XPath '//dns:settings/component/FirstLogonCommands' -Namespace $ns` and some other variations. Still null. I don't see how the other question answers this, except in a vague way. I'm trying to extrapolate from that answer how to get to a solution, but all I have is null output.

Comment: `$items = Select-Xml -Xml $xmlDocument -XPath '//dns:settings' -Namespace $ns` should give you a list of settings

Comment: It does, but then I'm still back to where I started. `$items = Select-Xml -Xml $xmlDocument -XPath '//dns:settings/component' -Namespace $ns` still gives me `null` and so I again have no way to select the `FirstLogonCommands` node. I still don't know how to enter that node (with the xml in the OP above). How do I select `<component name="Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Setup" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS">` and then the `FirstLogonCommands` under there?

Comment: I'm still trying more variations, but so far not found how to get the right way, e.g. `$items = Select-Xml -Xml $xmlDocument -XPath '//dns:settings/component[@name="Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Setup"]/FirstLogonCommands' -Namespace $ns`, or `$items = Select-Xml -Xml $xmlDocument -XPath '//dns:settings[@pass="oobeSystem"]/component[@name="Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Setup"]/FirstLogonCommands' -Namespace $ns`. As per the OP, 'm looking to get the items inside the `FirstLogonCommands` node.

Comment: You just need to include the dns for each item in the path `Select-Xml -Xml $xmlDocument -XPath '//dns:settings[@pass="oobeSystem"]/dns:component[@name="Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Setup"]/dns:FirstLogonCommands' -Namespace $ns`

Comment: That's great, it works, and thankyou , but this was far from obvious to me on how to proceed here. I think this is a valid question that could benefit others in a similar situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to include the dns for each item in the path:

```ps
$ns = @{dns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:unattend"}
Select-Xml -Xml $xmlDocument -XPath '//dns:settings[@pass="oobeSystem"]/dns:component[@name="Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Setup"]/dns:FirstLogonCommands' -Namespace $ns
```

Answer (score 2):

You can drill down where you want this way.

```
$DesiredSetting = $xmlDocument.unattend.settings | Where-Object {$_.pass -eq 'oobeSystem'}
$DesiredComponent = $DesiredSetting.component | Where-Object {$_.name -eq 'Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Setup'}
$firstLogonCommands = $DesiredComponent.FirstLogonCommands
```

But make sure you place the `$null` on the left side of `-eq`, otherwise it will not work correctly.

```
if ($null -eq $firstLogonCommands.'#comment') {
   Write-Output "FirstLogonCommands section not found under 'Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Setup' component in the 'oobeSystem' settings pass."
} else {
   Write-Output "FirstLogonCommands section found:"
   Write-Output $firstLogonCommands.InnerXml
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To juxtapose and complement the existing answers:

- [derloopkat's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78102988/45375) is the **direct solution** to your problem: It corrects your [`Select-Xml`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-xml) call to make it namespace-aware, via a hashtable of namespace-prefix-to-URI mapping(s) passed to `-Namespace`, and shows that *each* element name in your [XPath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) query must be namespace-qualified.

  - As an aside:

    - You don't need to load your XML text into an `[xml]` ([`System.Xml.XmlDocument`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Xml.XmlDocument)) instance first: `Select-Xml` has a `-Content` parameter that directly accepts XML *text*.
    - In cases where you do need an `[xml]` instance based on in-memory XML text, you can just cast the text (string) directly to `[xml]`, e.g. `[xml] '<foo>bar</foo>'`
- [Darin's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78103824/45375) shows a **namespace-agnostic OO alternative** that relies on [PowerShell's adaptation of the `[xml]` DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77552661/45375):

  - In essence, PowerShell allows you to treat any parsed `[xml]` document as an *object graph* that you can drill into using regular *dot notation*, because PowerShell surfaces XML (child) elements and XML attributes *as namespace-less properties* on each object (XML node) in the graph.
  - E.g., `$xmlDocument.unattend.settings` enumerates all `<settings>` child elements of the `<unattend>` root element; in other words: it is the equivalent of XPath `/unattend/settings`, without having to worry about namespaces.
- [jdweng's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78101825/45375) uses an **alternative XML-parsing API**, [`System.Linq.Xml.XDocument`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xdocument):

  - While this API is newer than `[xml]` ([`System.Xml.XmlDocument`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Xml.XmlDocument)) and in many ways more convenient than the latter, it is important to note:

    - Both APIs are and will likely continue to be supported.
    - **In the context of *PowerShell***, given the aforementioned convenient XML DOM adaptation based on `[xml]`, and the fact that `Select-Xml` is also `[xml]`-based, it is ***usually* simpler to stick with `[xml]`**:

      - Case in point: jdweng's answer in essence *manually recreates* (in flattened form) the DOM adaptation of the input XML document  that you get *for free* when you use `[xml]` (and, as an aside, does so in an inefficient fashion, due to repeated `Add-Member` calls and the unnecessary use of an `[ArrayList]` instance to manually create an output list).
      - With respect to *XPath* support, specifically, the two APIs offer very similar API surfaces, so there's also no advantage to using `[System.Xml.Linq.XDocument]` - see below.
      - However, when it comes to ***structural* modifications of XML documents**, the **`System.Linq.Xml.XDocument`-based API *is* preferable** even in PowerShell; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78124801/45375) for an example.

---

For the sake of completeness: Here's the **equivalent [`[System.Xml.Linq.XDocument]`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xdocument) XPath solution**:

```bash
# Simplified input XML
# 'THE TEXT OF INTEREST.' is what should be extracted.
$xml = @"
<unattend xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:unattend" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State">
  <settings pass="offlineServicing"></settings>
  <settings pass="windowsPE"></settings>
  <settings pass="oobeSystem">
    <component name="Microsoft-Windows-International-Core" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS">
      <InputLocale>0809:00000809</InputLocale>
    </component>
    <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Setup" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS">
      <FirstLogonCommands>
        THE TEXT OF INTEREST.
      </FirstLogonCommands>
    </component>
  </settings>
</unattend>
"@

# Parse the XML text.
$doc = [System.Xml.Linq.XDocument]::Parse($xml)

# Create an XML namespace manager that declares the input XML's
# default namespace URI and associates it with a self-chosen prefix, 'dns'
# NOTE:
#   * The analogous thing happens behind the scenes for [xml], when you pass
#     a hashtable with prefix-to-URI mappings to Select-Xml -Namespace,
#     as in derloopkat's answer.
$nsm = [System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager]::new([System.Xml.NameTable]::new())
$nsm.AddNamespace('dns', 'urn:schemas-microsoft-com:unattend')

# Now base your XPath query on the self-chosen namespace prefix, making
# sure that it is used with each element name in the path.
[System.Xml.XPath.Extensions]::XPathSelectElement(
  $doc, 
  '//dns:settings[@pass="oobeSystem"]/dns:component[@name="Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Setup"]/dns:FirstLogonCommands', 
  $nsm
).Value.Trim()
```

The above prints `THE TEXT OF INTEREST.`, proving that the text content of the element of interest was successfully extracted.

Comment: I disagree.  Most people who use the Net Library strongly recommend using Xml Linq over XML.

Comment: @jdweng, this answer explains why using `[xml]` is easier _from PowerShell_, because of the integration built into its language and cmdlets. This is separate from the question which API is preferable _overall_ (as the answer notes, _in general_ the `System.Xml.Linq` API is in many ways _more convenient_).

Comment: Easier doesn't necessarily mean better.  XML Linq has much better methods than XML.  XML is definitely not better. The legacy libraries requires more lines of code to perform same as Xml Linq.

Comment: @jdweng, no one is making the argument that `System.Xml` is better. The argument that _is_ being made is: Due to its integration into PowerShell, its use _there_ is usually easier, more concise, and therefore generally better. Nothing stops you from using `System.Xml.Linq` in PowerShell (a testament to its flexibility), but _in most cases_ it'll be _more work_, as evidenced by your own answer (as noted, it is a cumbersome recreation of what PowerShell's `System.Xml` DOM adaptation gives you for free), and readers should be made aware of that.

Comment: I keep on telling you that concise is not good.  It was called Power Programming in the 1960's and most large Programming Companies do not allow it because it is hard to maintain.  Code must be easily readable.

Comment: @jdweng, this is not the place for such discussions, though I will provide one hint: pitting concision vs. maintainability/readability is a false dichotomy.

Answer (score 0):

Try following code which uses XML Linq

```
using assembly System.Xml.Linq 

# Load the XML content
$xml = @"
<unattend xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:unattend" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State">
  <settings pass="offlineServicing">
  </settings>
  <settings pass="windowsPE">
    <component name="Microsoft-Windows-International-Core-WinPE" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS">
      <SetupUILanguage>
        <UILanguage>en-US</UILanguage>
      </SetupUILanguage>
      <InputLocale>0809:00000809</InputLocale>
      <SystemLocale>en-GB</SystemLocale>
      <UILanguage>en-US</UILanguage>
      <UserLocale>en-GB</UserLocale>
    </component>
  </settings>
  <settings pass="oobeSystem">
    <component name="Microsoft-Windows-International-Core" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS">
      <InputLocale>0809:00000809</InputLocale>
    </component>
    <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Setup" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS">
      <FirstLogonCommands>
        <!-- Content here -->
      </FirstLogonCommands>
    </component>
  </settings>
</unattend>
"@
$doc = [System.Xml.Linq.XDocument]:: Parse($xml)
$ns = $doc.Root.GetDefaultNamespace()

$table = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()
foreach($setting in $doc.Descendants($ns + 'settings'))
{
   $newRow = [pscustomobject]@{}
   $newRow | Add-Member -NotePropertyName pass -NotePropertyValue $setting.Attribute('pass').Value
   
   $component = $setting.Element($ns + 'component')

   if($component -ne $null)
   {
      foreach($attribute in $component.Attributes())
      {
         $newRow | Add-Member -NotePropertyName $attribute.Name.LocalName -NotePropertyValue $attribute.Value
      }
      foreach($element in $component.Elements())
      {
         if(-not $element.HasElements)
         {
            $newRow | Add-Member -NotePropertyName $element.Name.LocalName -NotePropertyValue $element.Value
         }
      }

   }

   $table.Add($newRow) | out-null
}
$table | Format-List
```

Here is the results

```
pass : offlineServicing

pass                  : windowsPE
name                  : Microsoft-Windows-International-Core-WinPE
processorArchitecture : amd64
publicKeyToken        : 31bf3856ad364e35
language              : neutral
versionScope          : nonSxS
InputLocale           : 0809:00000809
SystemLocale          : en-GB
UILanguage            : en-US
UserLocale            : en-GB

pass                  : oobeSystem
name                  : Microsoft-Windows-International-Core
processorArchitecture : amd64
publicKeyToken        : 31bf3856ad364e35
language              : neutral
versionScope          : nonSxS
InputLocale           : 0809:00000809
```

Comment: Offering a technologically unrelated solution without addressing the problem stated in the question and without explaining _why_ a different technology may be called for - if at all - is unhelpful. In the case at hand, the OP's problem had a straightforward solution that required only a small tweak to their existing code, as shown in [derloopkat's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78102988/45375).

Comment: @mklement0 : My answer is superior and using the newer XML Linq Net Library instead of the legacy XML Net Library.

Comment: @derloopkat's is definitely the straight path to the answer that I needed, but I do like seeing this Linq alternative that may be useful to anyone that comes to this question to see both approaches (and I'll almost certainly make use of this Linq also so I appreciate both answers).

Comment: I posted my results. My solution gives a flat results which is easier to work with than other solutions.  I could of just done the Xml Load method and go same simple results as derloopkat's, but I went must further a parse the entire file.

Comment: @YorSubs: The Linq alternative is great in C#, but `[xml]` is usually the better choice _in PowerShell_, for the reasons now spelled out in my answer. Case in point: this answer  _manually recreates_ (in flattened form) the DOM adaptation of the input XML document that you get _for free_ when you use `[xml]` (see Darin's answer). By contrast, using a proper XPath solution - which is what your question calls for - is quite similar between Linq and `[xml]`, so there's also no advantage there (see my answer for how to use XPath queries with Linq).

Comment: @YorSubs, as an aside: Not only does this answer not address the question as asked and offers a technologically unrelated solution without an explanation (_properly framing_ an unrelated offering along with a _motivation_ would  be fine, but that is absent here), the solution that it does offer is implemented in an inefficient, PowerShell-unidiomatic way; since this is a repeat occurrence, the comments I've made on [this older answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76011282/45375) apply here too.