# Removing and Update Xml node using Powershell

Tags: xml, powershell, dom

I have the following xml

```
  <system.net>
    <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true" />
  </system.net>
```

And would like to replace the "defaultProxy" node above with this below using Powershell

```
<system.net>    
   <defaultProxy>
      <proxy usesystemdefault="True" proxyaddress="http://xxxxx" bypassonlocal="True" />
      <bypasslist>
        <add address="yyyyyy" />
      </bypasslist>
    </defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```

Ive seen similar post but not with nested nodes. I just cant get my head around it

Comment: Doing it via XSLT would be the easiest rout. And call that XSLT via Powershell.

Answer (score 3):

XSLT way and three lines of Powershell.

**Input XML**

```
<system.net>
    <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true"/>
</system.net>
```

**XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"
                encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <!--Identity transform-->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="defaultProxy">
        <xsl:copy>
            <proxy usesystemdefault="True"
                   proxyaddress="http://xxxxx"
                   bypassonlocal="True"/>
            <bypasslist>
                <add address="yyyyyy"/>
            </bypasslist>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output XML**

```
<system.net>
  <defaultProxy>
    <proxy usesystemdefault="True" proxyaddress="http://xxxxx" bypassonlocal="True"/>
    <bypasslist>
      <add address="yyyyyy"/>
    </bypasslist>
  </defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```

**Powershell**

```
$xslt = New-Object System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform;
$xslt.load("e:\Temp\Powershell\Process.xslt")
$xslt.Transform("e:\Temp\Powershell\Input.xml", "e:\Temp\Powershell\Output.xml")
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit tedious, but you can construct a new `<defaultProxy />` replacement like this:

```bash
# parse xml document
$configurationDoc = [xml]@'
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.net>
    <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true" />
  </system.net>
</configuration>
'@

# create new <defaultProxy /> element
$newDefaultProxy = $configurationDoc.CreateElement('defaultProxy')

# create new <proxy /> element, add to previous element
$newProxy = $configurationDoc.CreateElement('proxy')
$newProxy.SetAttribute('usesystemdefault', $true) 
$newProxy.SetAttribute('proxyaddress', "http://xxxxx")
$newProxy.SetAttribute('bypassonlocal', $True)
$newDefaultProxy.AppendChild($newProxy) |Out-Null

# create new <bypasslist /> element with child node, add to previous element
$newBPL = $configurationDoc.CreateElement('bypasslist')
$addresses = @('address_goes_here')
foreach($address in $addresses) {
  $newAdd = $configurationDoc.CreateElement('add')
  $newAdd.SetAttribute('address', $address)
  $newBPL.AppendChild($newAdd) |Out-Null
}
$newDefaultProxy.AppendChild($newBPL) |Out-Null

# replace existing defaultProxy element
$existingDefaultProxy = $configurationDoc.SelectSingleNode('//defaultProxy')
$existingDefaultProxy.ParentNode.ReplaceChild($newDefaultProxy, $existingDefaultProxy) |Out-Null
```

To save the document:

```
$configurationDoc.Save($(Convert-Path path\to\export.xml))
```

Comment: Im geting error "Exception calling "ReplaceChild" with "2" argument(s): "The node to be removed is not a child of this node.""

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78108521/45375) discusses how it is *usually* better to use the [`System.Xml.XmlDocument`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Xml.XmlDocument)-based .NET API in PowerShell (where that type is also surfaced as `[xml]`), due to the latter's tight integration with PowerShell.

However, **when it comes to performing *structural modifications* to XML documents, the [`System.Xml.Linq.XDocument`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Xml.Linq.XDocument)-based API is superior** - and is notably *generally* superior for use *outside* of PowerShell, such as in C#.

```bash
using namespace System.Xml.Linq

# Determine the *full path* to the input XML file.
# Adjust as needed, but a full path is essential, because .NET's working dir.
# usually differs from PowerShell's
$xmlFilePath = Convert-Path ./file.xml

# Parse the file into an [XDocument] instance.
$doc = [XDocument]::Load($xmlFilePath)

# Construct the new <defaultProxy> element from a string:
$newElem = [XElement]::Parse('
<defaultProxy>
<proxy usesystemdefault="True" proxyaddress="http://xxxxx" bypassonlocal="True" />
<bypasslist>
  <add address="yyyyyy" />
</bypasslist>
</defaultProxy>
')

# Replace the root element's child nodes (here: the existing <defaultProxy> element)
# with the newly constructed one.
$doc.Root.ReplaceNodes($newElem)

# Save the results back to the input file.
$doc.Save($xmlFilePath)
```